# I need to show this image and text in the custom listView

Tags: android

I need to show this image and text in the custom listView 
the error is .....

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
>                         at com.example.majdaldawoud.appshow.applistview$customAdapter.getView(applistview.java:61)

```
    ListView lstv;
    String[] DESC = {"hi", "majd"};
    int[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_applistview);

        lstv=findViewById(R.id.lv);
        customAdapter custom = new customAdapter();
        lstv.setAdapter(custom);

    }
    class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return IMAGES.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewrow,null);
            ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES[i]);
            textView.setText(DESC[i]);
            return view;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: error in get view method

Comment: Post your layout `R.layout.listviewrow`, It looks like you don't have a `TextView` with id `textView` there.

Comment: Pass some data to your Adapter friend

Comment: Seems your texview id is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in customAdapter, like below:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i; //not return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your listviewrow.xml file in which you declare textview id check once again both are same or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    ListView lstv;
    String[] DESC = {"hi", "majd"};
    int[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_applistview);

        lstv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        customAdapter custom = new customAdapter(this);
        lstv.setAdapter(custom);

    }
    class customAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
       Context mContext;
       public customAdapter(Context context){
         this.mContext = context;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return IMAGES.length;
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;//return item id 
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.listviewrow, null);
            ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(IMAGES[i]));
            textView.setText(DESC[i]);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure `R.layout.listviewrow` have an imageView and a textView id. Otherwise, issue not be resolved.
Your `listviewrow` will look like.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
      android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textSize="20sp" 
      android:paddingTop="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: at com.example.majdaldawoud.appshow.applistview$customAdapter.getView(applistview.java:55)

Comment: in the line Imaageview .setimageresource

Comment: @MajdAlDawood Your initial problem already fixed based on my question. Now you face for showing an image from drawable. I just update my answer. Please have a look.